# JPanel does not appear when i try to add it to ContentPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, contentpane

I'm having a problem trying to change JPanels by using buttons. I have a JFrame with 2 panels, 1 of them is for the buttons, which i want them to always be showed. The other one is the one that i will be switching everytime i press one ot the buttons of the other panel. The problem is that everytime i press them nothing really ever displays, i keep my buttons but the other panel that i call does not appear.

Code for one of the buttons is as follows

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        ReparacaoPanel r = new ReparacaoPanel(this, this.jPanel1);
        this.getContentPane().remove(this.jPanel1);
        this.getContentPane().add(r);
        //this.setContentPane(r);
        this.visiblePanel.setVisible(false);
        this.visiblePanel = r;
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

        r.setLocation(200, 200);
        this.getContentPane().revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }
```

If i try to use "this.setContentPane(r);" (it sets the frame to only show the panel) the panel shows. But when i try to call it as i'm trying to do in the code above nothing is showed apart from the panel that has the buttons.

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, it does not seem to be a problem with the JPanel that i'm trying to call as it shows if used alone.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Consider using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between visible panels.

Comment: Question seems similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16079886/3165552)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but that does not fit what i'm trying to do. I need them to switch right away and not calling for a cardlayout to switch them.
I've seen this working, i just don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: *"I need them to switch right away and not calling for a cardlayout to switch them."*  Does that mean something in your head?  In mine, it sounds like complete nonsense.

Comment: it's not exactly the same. As i said on the topic if i use this.setContentPane(r); the panel shows, but i need it to just switch one of the panels of the mainframe to the one that i'm calling

Comment: The only maybe slightly acceptable reason to not use the `CardLayout` could be that the layout switches between already known panels. A more dynamic scenario then just keeps adding a new panel to it to switch to right after adding it. Even then i would stick to it.

Comment: It's not nonsense, this is for an academic project and i'm supposed to do it this way. If i present it with card layout they'll go like: "What the hell is that? Why use such a thing? CardLayout for 7 options? that is more clicks than buttons, not pratical". I'd prefer to use menus rather than using CardLayout. Then again i would prefer to get this working rather than using anything else

Comment: What is visiblePanel?  what is the declaration of `this`?  What is jPanel1?  One of the things about doing odd stuff in UI -- like stoutly refusing to use standard layout managers for reasons that are unclear -- is that it's harder to trust that other parts of your code can be filled in *a priori* as though they were written like other code we've seen.  You can illustrate your problem with a small example -- JFrame, 2-3 JPanels, a button, and demo what you're trying to do in less than 100 lines, and then post the whole thing. That's what I recommend you do now.

Comment: thanks, but i already figured it out, thanks to isi's answer. I didn't tested the full example but i started thinking about the possibility of it being hidden by using automatic resizing operations so i tried to remove this.pack(); and aparently it was hiding the panel, i don't understand why tho. Maybe i'll just use setLocation get get it where i really want it and set a default size and make it not resizable. Thanks for everything

Comment: Resizing comes in handy with layout managers. Have you considered using an WYSIWYG editor to create your GUI, like the free google window builder inside of eclipse? This makes it a lot easier to layout a program and is neat when it produces code of good quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this working example for switching manually between panels. Which produces this output.

[image] [image].........

### Some tiny `NumberPanel`

Every new instance shows another number in the center.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class NumberPanel extends JPanel {
    private static int counter = 0;
    public NumberPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("" + counter++);
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(lblNewLabel);
    }
}
```

### Setting up a frame

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.getContentPane().remove(numberPanel);
            numberPanel = new NumberPanel();
            frame.getContentPane().add(numberPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
        }
    });
    panel.add(btnNewButton);

    numberPanel = new NumberPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(numberPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
}
```

### Testprogram

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class TestPanelSwitch {
    private JFrame frame;
    private NumberPanel numberPanel;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestPanelSwitch window = new TestPanelSwitch();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public TestPanelSwitch() {
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        // see above
    }
}
```

### Back to the Question

I think you only need to `pack` your frame, like in the anonymous `ActionListener`.

```
frame.getContentPane().remove(numberPanel);
numberPanel = new NumberPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(numberPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
```

### EDIT

As leonidas mentioned it is also possible to revalidate the `frame`. This requires only to replace the upper call to `pack` by theese.

```
frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
```